# Looping over list of variables in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a list of variables (different sized numeric matrices) named Reach1 to Reach7

I want to plot them all as subplots in one figure.

Need a way to loop over each variable as below:

```
names = {'Reach1' 'Reach2' 'Reach3' 'Reach4' 'Reach5' 'Reach6' 'Reach7'};
for index = 1:7
    subplot(3,3,index)
    plot(names(index)(:,1),names(index)(:,2));hold on;
    plot(names(index)(:,5),names(index)(:,6));
    plot(names(index)(:,9),names(index)(:,10));hold off;
end
```

Is there a better way to do this in matlab?

Comment: What are you trying to access with this?
`names(index)(:,1)`

Comment: For example Reach1 is a 76x12 matrix,
`names(index)(:,1)` is plotting all of the 1st column of this matrix against the second column `names(index)(:,2)`

Comment: I can't really think of a much more efficient way to do this in matlab. You could declare the various column numbers before the loop to make edition those easier. You could also (if the number of names might change) replace the `index = 1:7` by `index = 1:length(names)`.

Comment: The best thing you could do is change the way you deal with the variables.  Isntead of creating a big list of variables with a number in the end, you should create a single cell array, that contains all the variables inside. This will solve also future problems you will (definetly) have, and will make you go far from the `eval` function, that is the best solution to your problem now. Note that even the creators of `eval` at Mathworks do disencourage the use of it.

Comment: @AnderBiguri I think `'Reach1'` designated that in this place 1st  array should be, etc. So the structure *is* in the form you suggest.

Comment: @Crowley I dont thing `'Reach`'` reffers to a 2D matrix, I think it reffers to a string, and the OP wants to evaluate a variable (not shown) with that name.

Comment: @AnderBiguri I've read Tommy's comment this way and his code as a try to handle it. On the other hand, in that case he could have written `names={<Reach1> <Reach2>...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access `names(index)` because it is `cell` array and those are accessed by `names{index}`.

If you want to access variable `Reach1(1,3)` by calling `names{1}(1,3)`, you will fail because Matlab will (try to) return `a` as an element of `char` array. This approach can be achieved by [eval](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eval.html) but do **NOT** do that! It has many [drawbacks](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/string-evaluation.html) and no benefit.

You can simplify your code using Matlabs features, that are not obvious but bloody useful.

Suppose we have all matrices in one cell array `Reaches={<Reach1>;<Reach2>;...}`:

```
Reaches={rand(4,12);rand(6,12);rand(8,12);rand(2,12);rand(9,12)}; %declare dummy variables
counter=0;

for Reach=Reaches
  counter=counter+1;
  subplot(3,3,counter);
  plot(Reach(:,[1,5,9]),Reach(:,2,6,10));
end
```

This code benefits from:

- [for](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/for.html?searchHighlight=for) is able to loop over array elements.
- [plot](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html?searchHighlight=plot) is able to process arrays.
- (Advanced) Array [indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/learn_matlab/array-indexing.html).

In this example appropriate element `names{ii}` is passed to `Reach` variable, counter `counter` is advanced and `plot` is supported by matrices containig columns 1, 5 and 9 and 2, 6 and 10 as x and y values, respectively.